# How to specify the Engine used for SSL functions in OpenSSL Library?

Tags: ssl, openssl, openssl-engine

I understand how openssl ```ENGINE and evp works, and how to use engines in libcrypto C language programming(applying digest/encryption/signing etc. for plain data).

Now I would like to learn **how to apply engine for all cryptographic processes behind the SSL functions**, including cipher suits. It seems that there aren't parameters or initializing functions for SSL functions to specify `ENGINE` like what in EVP_EncryptInit_ex(), etc.

I know the cryptographic processes in libssl are based on libcrypto, so maybe I can use the same way, namely specify the default engine before calling any SSL functions:

```
    ENGINE_load_dynamic();
    foo_engine = ENGINE_by_id("foo");
    int init_res = ENGINE_init(foo_engine);
    ENGINE_set_default(foo_engine, ENGINE_METHOD_ALL);

    SSL_CTX_new()
    ......
```

Does it work?

Or should I load openssl.cnf instead? Although I think it is the same thing.